# 68060 CLKEN and CLK pins

Tags: amiga-3000, motorola-680x0

Using an 68060 to 68040 Amiga adapter on another brand.

The adapter ties the 68040 BCLK to the 68060 CLKEN. The CLK pin on the adapter is left floating.

To run the CPU with 1/2 bus will I need to provide the adapter with the 68040 PCLK (2x), or should the 68060 be pulled high or low via a resistor? Or is this a normal configuration?

Most information on these is for the various Amiga boards, and there is some loss understanding the terminology for me.